# CustomTkinter Treeview Empty Column Issue

Tags: tkinter, treeview, customtkinter

I am trying to output "outputs" into a table on my CustomTkinter GUI. While it outputs correctly, it consistently adds an empty column to the left-hand side of the table. The variable "outputs" changes depending on user interaction with the GUI.Here is the image of the table: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ug4oI.png). I am not sure how to remove this column (it does not appear to be an issue with the index of output or the columns in outputs):

```
   def format_results(outputs): #creates a nice table for the results depending on user selection 
                # Create a style
                style = ttk.Style()
                style.configure("Treeview", rowheight=65)
                self.treeview = ttk.Treeview(master=self.tabview.tab("Phenosimilars"))
                #outputs = outputs.reset_index(drop=True)
                columns = list(outputs.columns)
                self.treeview["columns"] = columns
                print(self.treeview["columns"])
                for col in columns:
                    self.treeview.heading(col, text=col)
                    print(f'This is {col}')
                    self.treeview.column(col, anchor="center")
                    print(f'This is {col}')
            
                # Insert data into the table
                for index, row in outputs.iterrows():
                    self.treeview.insert("",index, values=tuple(row))
                    
                # Add horizontal scrollbar
                h=Scrollbar(self.treeview, orient='horizontal')
                h.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill='x')
                h.config( command = self.treeview.xview )

                # Add Treeview to the parent tab
                self.treeview.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
               
                return(outputs)
```

I tried resetting the output index, and checked that the output columns were correct: ('Isomap Phenosimilars', 'Isomap Pearson Correlation Values', 'Isomap Tanimoto Score') and here is what it prints between the column creation: This is Isomap Phenosimilars
This is Isomap Phenosimilars
This is Isomap Pearson Correlation Values
This is Isomap Pearson Correlation Values
This is Isomap Tanimoto Score
This is Isomap Tanimoto Score

Comment: The leftmost column is the *tree* column which can be hidden by setting `show="headings"` when creating the treeview.